# Access is multiplying my query count by 38.... why?

Tags: ms-access, count

My data looks like

---

ID   -  InputID

- 1   -    data1
- 2    -   data2
- 3   -    data2
- 4   -    data2
- 5   -    data6

If I run a query that produces the count of each data input:

```
SELECT First(InventoryData2.InputID) AS FirstOfInputID, Count(InventoryData2.InputID) AS InputItemCount FROM InventoryInputT, InventoryData2 GROUP BY InventoryData2.InputID HAVING (((Count(InventoryData2.InputID))>=1));
```

Which, based on the data, SHOULD provide something along the lines of

---

data1: 1

---

data2: 3

---

data3: 1

---

HOWEVER, access shows my count totals as:

---

data1: = 38

---

data2: = 114

---

data3 = 38

---

ANY IDEA WHY?

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Honestly it was just a suggested tag, and seeing how I had some SQL code I thought it may be somewhat relevant. Apologies if it wasn't.

Comment: @Strawberry: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275170/3820271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the query is producing a Cartesian product. That is, each and every row from `InventoryInputT` is being matched to each and every row in `InventoryData2`, a cross product, because the query specifies a join operation with no condition to limit which rows are to be matched with each other.

The GROUP BY operation is collapsing the rows. Remove the GROUP BY clause and all of the aggregate functions, return just the detail rows, and you will see what's happening.

Comment: ahhh yes, just realized that the 'InventoryInputT' shouldn't be there. When I remove it then the count works as it should